UIViewController inside multiple coordinators in "Coordinator" pattern in Swift?
I've read about Coordinator pattern and in all cases it is described as below:
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var coordinator: CoordinatorProtocol?
}

protocol CoordinatorProtocol: AnyObject { }

class Coordinator: CoordinatorProtocol {
    var navigationController: UINavigationController

    func showSomeViewController() {
        navigationController.push(SomeViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}

But what to do if I need to add Coordinator2 (CoordinatorProtocol2) which is independent from Coordinator but it can create and use SomeViewController? In other words how to make SomeViewController using 2 or more coordinators?
Add weak var coordinator: CoordinatorProtocol2? inside view controller? Replace with weak var coordinator: (CoordinatorProtocol1 & CoordinatorProtocol2)??

You can define an interface that combines these two. Or simply create a type alias for them.
protocol CombineCoordinatorProtocol: CoordinatorProtocol, CoordinatorProtocol2 { }

//OR

typealias CombineCoordinator = CoordinatorProtocol & CoordinatorProtocol2

Then you're able to inject it as normal into SomeViewController
class SomeController {
    //Both are fine
    weak var coordinator: CombineCoordinator?
    weak var coordinator2: CombineCoordinatorProtocol?
}


There is a problem with your code - CombineCoordinator or CombineCoordinatorProtocol require each coordinator to implement 2 protocols simultaneously but these 2 coordinators are usually totally different and don't depend on each other. In this case it is even better for me to create a variable of a common coordinator type and optional computed properties which may return a coordinator of a concrete type.

From my perspective, there is nothing wrong with this. I assumed that you're applying a kind of clean architecture with a few layers such as use case, coordinator, view model, etc... So, a scene (controller) may take a single coordinator (to navigate to other scenes, I guess). Thus, numerous coordinators here depend on your purpose, and combining them together is fine.

tried to ask Perplexity (like chatgpt). It suggest something strange - use Strategy pattern as a mediator between UIViewController and Coordinator

I believe you're confused. Coordinator/Navigator pattern is not the same as Strategy pattern. Strategy is a behavioral design that selects an implementation among a group of different algorithms/implementations. On the other hand, Coordinator/Navigator is used to manage the flow, to decouple navigation logic from controllers.

Possibly I have found a solution which is similar to your one but conforms to SOLID too. https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/mediator/swift/example   I can create Mediator class which implements all the coordinator protocols and works with inner Coordinator classes like with components. In other words UIViewController contains and uses single Mediator object which contains and uses multiple Coordinator objects which may me (or not) related to each other.
